# Python requests: download only if newer

Tags: python, python-requests, date-math

What is the standard pythonic way to download a new file from a server only if the server copy is newer than the local one?

Either my python-search-fu is very weak today, or one really does needs to roll their own date-time parser and comparer like below. Is there really no `requests.header.get_datetime_object('last-modified')`? or `request.save_to_file(url, outfile, maintain_datetime=True)`?

```
import requests
import datetime

r = requests.head(url)
url_time = r.headers['last-modified']
file_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(dstFile))
print url_time  #emits 'Sat, 28 Mar 2015 08:05:42 GMT' on my machine
print file_time #emits '2015-03-27 21:53:28.175072' 

if time_is_older(url_time, file_time):
    print 'url modtime is not newer than local file, skipping download'
    return
else:
    do_download(url)
    os.utime(dstFile, url_time) # maintain server's file timestamp

def time_is_older(str_time, time_object):
    ''' Parse str_time and see if is older than time_object.
        This is a fragile function, what if str_time is in different locale?
    '''
    parsed_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(str_time, 
        #Fri, 27 Mar 2015 08:05:42 GMT
        '%a, %d %b %Y %X %Z')
    return parsed_time < time_object
```

Comment: You can compare `time.time()` values (time in seconds since the epoch).

Comment: @user1656850 yes. My concern with that, perhaps not well expressed well enough, is that I would still be creating my own string-to-time-object parser parameters in order to use time.time(), and that since I would be writing my own I'd be pretty much guaranteed to have bugs or omissions. My Q is trying to find the idiomatic solution. I'm sure there must be one for this common scenario, I just haven't figured out how to find it!

Comment: This falls short of a full answer, but you will generally want to use the HTTP If-Modified-Since and have the server only send the data if it's more recent.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
import requests
import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse as parsedate
r = requests.head(url)
url_time = r.headers['last-modified']
url_date = parsedate(url_time)
file_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(dstFile))
if url_date > file_time :
    download it !
```

Comment: The weired thing is that I get the last modified header only when i am using get request, no last modified in head request

Comment: I'm not seeing `last-modified` (or `Last-Modified`) in the headers via `head` or via `get`. There's a `Date:` but that updates every time I download. How does this work?   (My URL in question is a Google Doc "Anyone can view" sharing URL.)

Answer (score 4):

I used the following code, which also takes the timezone into account and makes sure both datetime objects are aware.

```py
import datetime
import requests
from dateutil.parser import parse as parsedate

r = requests.head(url)
url_datetime = parsedate(r.headers['Last-Modified']).astimezone()
file_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(path.getmtime(dst_file)).astimezone()
if(url_date > file_time):
    user_agent = {"User-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0"}
    r = requests.get(url, headers=user_agent)
    with open(file, 'wb') as fd:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(4096):
            fd.write(chunk)
```

Answer (score 0):

The HEAD verb doesn't include the Last-Modified header, but you can use the ETag instead. This is an opaque string, typically a file hash, that will change if the resource changes. It's more work, and requires local storage of the hash. You could also consider using the requests-cache module, which might be a simpler solution. Here's what I came up with:

```
def podcast_updated(podcast: Podcast) -> bool:
    # Based on our saved last-updated time, are there new episodes? If not, don't
    # hammer their server. Internet manners. Method - call HEAD instead of GET
    # Note that HEAD doesn't include a timestamp, but does include the cache ETag, so
    # we simply snapshot the etag to disk and see if it differs.
    filename = podcast.name + '-timestamp.json'
    try:
        r = requests.head(podcast.rss_url)
        url_etag = r.headers['ETag']
        file_etag = open(filename, 'r').read()

        if file_etag == url_etag:
            log.info(f'No new episodes found in podcast {podcast.name}')
            return False
    except FileNotFoundError:
        log.warning(f'File {filename} not found, creating.')

    open(filename, 'w').write(url_etag)
    return True
```